# How to iterate over FormArray in FormGroup in an Angular reactive Form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

The Structure of my form is as shown below

```
-MainForm(ParentForm)
 -FormGroup(MedicineGroup)
  -FormArray(MedicineArray)
```

I wanted to iterate `MedicineArray` for which, i did some research and wrote the below code

```
for (let control of soForm.get('MedicineGroup').controls['MedicineArray'].controls) {
    medObj.name.push(control.controls['MedName'].value);
  }
```

The code is working fine but i am getting a warning, which says

```
Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
```

Is there any other or better way to iterate a FormArray which is inside a FormGroup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using `['controls']` instead of `.controls`:

```
for (let control of soForm.get('MedicineGroup')['controls']['MedicineArray']['controls']) {
    // ...
}
```

Another option would be:

```
const formArray = soForm.get('MedicineGroup.MedicineArray') as FormArray;
console.log(formArray);
```

It's a good practice to access nested controls using dot notation.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this is occurring is because the type system understands that you have an AbstractControl, because [`AbstractControl.prototype.get()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) returns an `AbstractControl`, but it doesn't know which concrete AbstractControl you are referencing, so accessing a `controls` property causes this warning.

You have some options as to how to solve it, casting or introducing another symbol, but the method is the same: provide better type information:

```
let aFormArray: FormArray = soForm.get('MedicineGroup.MedicineArray');

for (let c of aFormArray.controls) {
    medObj.name.push(c.controls['MedName'].value);
}
```